# Logger in JavaScript (node.js+electron.atom) to MySQL

Tags: node.js, logging, electron

I tried to find the solution on internet but I could not find anything about this issue.

I've found :

sentry (raven.js).
Node-Loggly
Bunyan
Winston
Morgan

But I couldn't find any information about saving log errors from logger to MySQL or SqlLite.

I have just worked for first time with log4net and I need something like this.

My application will not have connection to internet, for this reason I will package it in Electron Atom.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) along with [winston-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-mysql)